# Marker handle in angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I need to get the handle of a marker in order to set the icon when I have a ng-mouseover somewhere else on the page.

I push my markers into leaflet like this:

```
angular.extend($scope, 
    {markers: 
        {'id1': {lat:foo, lng:bar}, 
         'id2': {lat:foo, lng:bar}, ...
        }
    });
```

$scope.markers['id1'] returns the correct lat/lng dict. Here, i need the marker object so I can perform a marker.setIcon().

Looked a little into leafletMarkersHelpers but no success ...

Would appreciate any starting point.

Thanx

Best

/B

Answer (score 1):

There's an `leafletData` service for that. The Promise you get when you call `leafletData.getMarkers()` resolves with the Leaflet marker objects in the object with keys like in your scope.

```
leafletData.getMarkers().then(function (markers) {
    markers.id1.setIcon(...);
});
```

Comment: Thanx - leafletData is nice :)